# Выборка нескольких строк из MYSQL в одну таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Здравствуйте , допустим есть такая таблица в mysql 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с помощью PHP вывести его в браузер вот в таком виде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как суммировать численные значения знаю а вот как несколько строк объединить в одну никак не могу догнать. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: `select group_concat(name SEPARATOR ' '), sum(val1), sum(val2) from table1`

Comment: Благодарю ! то что надо !)

Comment: оформил ответом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для конкатенации строк при группировке в mysql имеется функция [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Синтаксис команды следующий:

```
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
         [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
             [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
         [SEPARATOR str_val])
```

То есть, что бы получить список имен без повторений по алфавиту объединенных через пробел (по умолчанию запятая), следует написать запрос вида:

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name ORDER BY name ASC SEPARATOR ' ')
```

по умолчанию максимальная длина объединяемой строки 1024 и задается переменной [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)