# Как объединить все строки столбца в одну строку?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

мне нужно получить из первой таблицы вторую. Из-за того, что у них id одинаковый, мне просто нужно вывести в одной строке все значения через запятую.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: GROUP_BY + GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выборка нескольких строк из MYSQL в одну таблицу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748011/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-mysql-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83)